# uigrid get current filtered data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using angularjs uigrid with no problems now I want to get the filtered data (the current visible rows ) when using columns filter ,I used the following code but it print last filtered data not current.

```
$scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged( $scope, function(){
$scope.filteredRows=$scope.gridApi.core.getVisibleRows($scope.gridApi.grid);
console.log($scope.filteredRows)
});
```

Html code

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: Refer this http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering. please share the angular html code

Comment: Ok I have shared html code

Comment: Just venturing a guess that the `filterChanged` event may not be what you need to be listening for as that doesn't alert you about when the rows have been rendered using the new filter, only that the filter was changed.

Comment: Based on the documentation for [ui.grid.core](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi), you may want to try using the `rowsVisibleChanged` event instead of the `filterChanged` event.